# Ruby on Rails - passing the value of an input field to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, link-to

Hi I am stuck here pretty bad. The senario is quite simple actually, I have an input field like this:

```
 %input.coupon_bar{:type => "text", :name=> "coupon", id=>"coupon_id"}/
```

And I want to pass whatever value is in that box to a different controller, I am trying to do it like this:

```
= link_to image_tag("ok_button.png", :border =>0), "/orders/new/", :coupon = #{$('.coupon_bar').val()}
```

I thought it would be simple using the jquery `$('.coupon_bar').val()` but I guess its not as simple as I thought... any help please????

Oh, and unlike [This StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430049/ruby-on-rails-getting-value-from-input-box-and-pass-to-another-page), my input field is not part of any form...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put it in a form? That would be much easier.

Anyway, you can use the onclick from the link to achieve your goal:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = '/orders/new/coupon='+ $('.coupon_bar').val();">
Text</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I see there two bad practices:

1. Don't hardcode your links
2. Avoid obstrusive js when possible

Here is what I suggest:

```
= link_to image_tag("ok_button.png", :border =>0), new_order_path, :id => "my_link"
```

And in your js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$().ready(function(){
    $('#my_link').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?coupon=' + $('.coupon_bar').val());
    });
});

</script>
```